# Ubuntu Failure To Load

Tags: 14.04

So I ran this command
`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` and my installation is legit screwed, I cannot do anything on it... it's like when I boot it, it doesn't find Ubuntu. Anyways now I want to erase everything with nothing remaining. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There are so many things you need to add:
Are you on a desktop or a laptop?
Are you booting from a netbook?
What is your computer manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

If you ran the command `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`, then you removed the metapackage which contains the components that make up the Ubuntu desktop. If you would like to restore it, you can do the following:

1. Boot up your system.
2. Press the keys `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to go into tty1. This will allow you to run commands on your system without logging in.
3. Log in with your normal username and password. If you don't know what this is, try to remember what details you gave it on first install. If you gave it your first and last name, it should be your first name but completely lowercase. Otherwise, remember to the last time you opened a terminal. Before the commands you type is USERNAME@HOSTNAME (for example, mine is `simon@semantic`) You would just need that username.
4. Type `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` into the command line and press your `Enter` key. This will update your repository information and install the ubuntu-desktop task again. If you connect to the internet via WiFi, you might want to check out [the Debian Wiki page on connecting to WiFi via the terminal](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse). It's always been helpful to me.
5. Reboot, and you should have a working desktop again.

Comment: When I click on ctrl + ALt +F1, nothing happens!

Comment: Do all three buttons simultaneously. It works on all releases of Ubuntu. If it doesn't work for you, then either you're doing it wrong or your hardware is broken.